# GCP DialogFlow, how can i pass inputcontext as value in webhook parameters

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

The below is the request body that is received by webhook. The intent i have has multiple input contexts. How do i know, from which context, is this intent called? There is no value that says, from which input context, this intent/action is called.

```
{
  "responseId": "a218fe93-f2d1-4bdd-bcdf-618195838f53-9a925d01",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "asEvent",
    "action": "asknAction",
    "parameters": {
  
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects//contexts/asknumbers-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 5,
        "parameters": {
        
      
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/b/contexts/defaultwelcomeintent-next-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 5,
        "parameters": {
         
     
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/b/contexts/askmultiplicationevent",
        "parameters": {
       
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/b/contexts/genmultiplicationdummy-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 4,
        "parameters": {
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/mlkaggle-288509/agent/sessions/4db2f820-cca0-989e-a2e7-fe7a9f6cbc2b/contexts/__system_counters__",
        "parameters": {
       
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/m09/agent/intents/192c043b-78a2-4af9-838e-ceebd89dc6c5",
      "displayName": "askMultiplication"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "source": "DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE",
    "payload": {}
  },
  "session": "projects/9/agent/sessions/4db2f820-cca0-989e-a2e7-fe7a9f6cbc2b"
}
```

Based on the input context, i would like to save data into database different values.

Comment: Did you check if input context is active?

Comment: what do you mean by "input context is active"? In the testing window, i can see, active contexts on the right side.